# Spring cannot open class path resource and saying it does not exist even when it does

Tags: java, xml

I am working with Spring framework in java. I want to configure my Spring app. So I am using XML. But I am getting an error saying:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [beans.xml]; nested exception is 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does 
not exist
```

This is the java code. I am getting this error when I run this java code.

```
package com.navaneeth.spyingdust;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
   
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");       
    
    }
}
```

What is wrong in here. Here I tried specifying the path too:

```
  public class App 
    {
        public static void main( String[] args ){
   
        ApplicationContext context =new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("src/main/java/beans.xml");      
    
    }
}
```

It is not working either. What is wrong in here. Please reply.

Comment: You should but your file into the directory ```src/main/resources```.

Comment: Its still not working.  Any other suggestions ?.